# Dongle Crashing

Tags: mac, wifi, crash

I updated my Mac to 10.9.5. Ater updating, my Vodafone 3G dongle started crashing.

```
Process:         Vodafone K4201 I [27832]
Path:            /Applications/Vodafone K4201 I.app/Contents/MacOS/Vodafone K4201 I
Identifier:      com.joinair.DataCardUI
Version:         PCM_VDFINDV1.0.0B12 (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [178]
Responsible:     Vodafone K4201 I [27832]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2015-05-08 09:44:18.725 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F1077)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  99DA69F5-4D28-3976-7AB8-4CF2C2DC18C0

Sleep/Wake UUID: A1619113-8549-4749-A1AC-785E2FF8F4F5

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000e03470c0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x97acc4a7 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x9801af0a CFRetain + 154
2   com.apple.CoreText               0x93523578 CreateFontWithFontURL(__CFURL const*, bool) + 408
3   com.apple.CoreText               0x93523246 TCGFontCache::CopyFont(__CFURL const*, bool) const + 102
4   com.apple.CoreText               0x9352303c TBaseFont::CopyNativeFont() const + 72
5   com.apple.CoreText               0x93522fb8 TBaseFont::CopyGraphicsFont() const + 26
6   com.apple.CoreText               0x935364ce CTFontCopyGraphicsFont + 108
7   QtGui                           0x0251f0ca non-virtual thunk to QDesktopWidget::~QDesktopWidget() + 51978
8   QtGui                           0x0252050a non-virtual thunk to QDesktopWidget::~QDesktopWidget() + 57162
9   QtGui                           0x025209f8 non-virtual thunk to QDesktopWidget::~QDesktopWidget() + 58424
10  QtGui                           0x027b59f5 QFontDatabase::load(QFontPrivate const*, int) + 1989
11  QtGui                           0x02794a58 QFontPrivate::engineForScript(int) const + 152
12  QtGui                           0x027aa0a2 QFontMetricsF::descent() const + 34
13  QtWebKit                         0x013ee04a QWebPluginDatabase::metaObject() const + 8485114
14  QtWebKit                         0x01201296 QWebPluginDatabase::metaObject() const + 6466374
```

Full crash log is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4c74f6ede0bd2915f175) (Github gist).

Comment: What have you tried so far (checking for updated drivers on the vendor web site would be a good first step for instance)?

Comment: i did bro. but facing same pro.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you described what you already tried. Also, an actual question (e.g. xyz does something - what can I do to zxy?) could improve your chances of finding someone who can answer it.